# как подключится к API КОМПАС-3D?

Tags: c++, компас-3d

```
#include <iostream>  // библиотека для раб с косолью и текстом
#include <atlbase.h> // com библиотека

// подключаем библиотеку
#include "C:\Program Files\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D v20\Bin\kAPI5.tlb"

#include "C:\Program Files\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D v20\SDK\Include\Ks_TLB.h"
#include "C:\Program Files\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D v20\SDK\Include\ksConstants.h"
#include "C:\Program Files\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D v20\SDK\Include\ldefin2D.h"
#include "C:\Program Files\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D v20\SDK\Include\ldefin3D.h"

// используем имя пространст
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // обявляем механизс сом
//  CoInitialize(NULL);

    // обявляем компас 
 // Kompas6API5::KompasObjectPtr Kompas;
    // вызываем компас прогу
//  Kompas.CreateInstance(L"Kompas.Application.5");


    // закрываем ком
//  CoUninitialize();


    KompasObjectPtr kompas;
    //Запускаем КОМПАС
    kompas.CreateInstance(L"KOMPAS.Application.5");
    //Делаем его видимым
    kompas->Visible = true;
    //Отключаемся от него
    kompas.Unbind();

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

действовал двумя вариантами из двух примеров (все не работают) .

первый

https://rutube.ru/video/24093081ddda7718e2759138ace15a57/?ysclid=lk72xz9vyy558926813

второй

https://habr.com/ru/companies/ascon/articles/328088/

**Вопрос звучит так вообще АПИ компаса рабочий ?? по документации выглядит очень печально.
Есть ли какие нибуть 3д программы (аналоги компаса 3д) с рабочим АПИ ??**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Всё прописал всё равно ничего не работает.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *"#include "C:\Program Files\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D v20\SDK\Include\Ks_TLB.h""* - ¿Что это за треш? ¿Где вы видели подключение заголовочных файлов по абсолютным путям? *"не работают"* - не является описанием проблемы

Comment: @user7860670 Здравствуйте спасибо за комментарий  , **так как надо делать то ??** я вижуал студей редко пользуюсь , там всё непонятно

Comment: Так тут вроде нет *ничего* специфичного для Visual Studio. Подключение такое же, как у других библиотек - добавляете в настройки компилятора нужные директивы препроцессора и пути к папкам с инклюдами, в настройки линкера - пути к папкам с библиотеками и список библиотек для линковки и все.

Comment: Вы же не первый раз на СО. что за картинки в вопросе?

Comment: @SergeyTatarintsev так я показываю что всë подключил и всë равно не работает.

Answer (score 0):

В журнале сборки английским по белому написано

> you need to apply an update/patch to your copy of c++Builder

Поэтому у вас два варианта - писать в билдере, или закатывать рукава и залазить по локоть в хэдеры, править проверки цппбилдера

PS: А вообще зоопарк у вас знатный - пишем в VS с использованием Qt приложение на основе хэдеров c++builder %)

Comment: По идее, API компаса основано на COM и его можно использовать откуда угодно.

Comment: можно. только без этих хэдеров

Comment: да , не это наверное просто компас гавно , попробую из куте если невыйдет то точно копас.